# Auto-mailing with Python - Message sometimes go ok and sometimes it scrambles entirely: why?

Tags: python, smtp

I'm trying to send several e-mails by Python script and it worked fine, but when I give it a list of addresses to keep sending it, the message is scrambled entirely (all parameters, including headers and html tags, go inside the mail body with no formatting at all). Why is this happening?

This is a government mail host, which is using Postfix as SMTP. The mail body contains images which are hosted in a own server public link. There are clickable links. Many other questions on this matter are about PHP. But I sense this has something to do with Python nature, some bug at run time.

Function build_message:

```py
def build_message(address):

    mail = EmailMessage()

    mail['From'] = MY_EMAIL
    mail['To'] = address
    mail['Subject'] = "Pesquisa de Sondagem Meios de Hospedagem - 2ª Etapa"
    mail.add_header('Disposition-Notification-To', MY_EMAIL)
    # mail.add_header('Return-Receipt-To', MY_EMAIL)

    mail.set_content(read_content(content_path))

    mail.add_alternative("""\
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p><a href=""" + link_url + """><img src=""" + image_path + """></a></p>
                        <p><a href=""" + link_url + """><img src=""" + image_path2 + """></a></p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>Caso n&atilde;o consiga abrir o question&aacute;rio pela imagem, clique no link abaixo:</p>
                        <p><a href=""" + link_url + """>""" + link_url + """</a></p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>Veja os resultados passados clicando 
                        <a href=""" + link_url2 + """>aqui</a>.</p>
                        <p>Augusto Ferronato Lima</p>
                        <p><strong>Gerência Técnica de Planejamento</strong></p>
                        <p><a href="mailto:""" + MY_EMAIL + """>""" + MY_EMAIL + """</a></p>
                        <p>(48) 3665-7436</p>
                        <p><a href="www.turismo.sc.gov.br">www.turismo.sc.gov.br</a></p>
                        <p><img src=""" + signature_url + """ /></p>
                    </body>
                </html>
                """, subtype='html')

    return mail
```

Connect and send function:

```py
def main(conn_host, conn_port):

    contacts = read_contacts(contacts_path)

    try:
        print(" ### Conectando em " + conn_host + ":" + conn_port + " ### ")

        s = smtplib.SMTP(host=conn_host, port=conn_port)
        s.set_debuglevel(1)

        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()

        s.login(MY_CREDENTIAL, PASSWORD)

        s.ehlo()
        print(" ### Success ###")


    except:
        print(" ### Success in " + conn_host + ":" + conn_port + " ### ")

    for contact in contacts:
        wait(2)
        mail = build_message(contact)
        print("Building message...")
        wait(5)

        try:
            print(" ### Sending message to: " + contact + " ### ")
            s.send_message(mail)
            wait(5)

            print(" ### Success mailing: " + contact + " ### ")

            del mail
            wait(90)
        except:
            print(" ### Error mailing: " + contact + " ### ")

    s.quit()
```

[Screenshot: OK/Scrambled versions of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esroh.png)

It looks good to me and it works with small tests, but whenever I add more addresses to my contacts list, the message gets scrambled on delivery. Please help.

Comment: Are you stripping whitespace from the contact addresses in `read_contacts`?  In particular end of line characters such as `'\r'` and `'\n'`?

Comment: That was exactly it! I guess my question points out how we must never forget to check our string parameters... and that extracted information (contained inside another software, above all) may contain unwanted metadata and invisible characters. Thank you and congratulations on the precise solution.